# Incrementing dates in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

this is my current code:

```
For z = 3 To 52
    Cells(z, 1) = Cells((z - 1), 3) + 7
Next z
```

Where cell z-1 is a date

I want to add 7 days to the previous cell however it's throwing an error, it this the right way to approach this issue or is there a simpler method?

Thank you

Comment: What error are you getting and where? What is in column C?

Comment: Is it a typo or on purpose that you are using column 1 (=A) on the left hand of the assignment but column 3 (=C) on the right side?

Comment: Yes thank you for spotting that, it was a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `DateAdd` function, use inside the loop:

```
Cells(Z, 1) = DateAdd("ww", 1, Cells((Z - 1), 3))
```

**Note**: the 1st parameter, is the `Interval`, set it to `"ww"`, which means weeks.

To read more about this function go to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262710(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: Hi,

I have tried this code however it is telling me I have a "type mismatch"?

Comment: @M.Ustun what values fo you have in Column "C" ? are they dates ?

Comment: Never mind it was just the script trying to take a string value from a cell that wasn't in date format. Many thanks for your help.